# Spring MVC Validation error message

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc

I have a problem with the validation in spring MVC. If I send an invalid request for the body, the application returns to the bad request but not my custom message.

The code is :

```
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<BaseModel> newTicket(@Valid @RequestBody Ticket ticket, Locale locale, BindingResult bindingResult ){
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        logger.info("error");
        throw new BadRequestException("Bad Request");
    }
```

if I try to put the application in debug mode, the if is never executed.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What is the error that it is logged?

Comment: No error, only blank response with 404 status code @NiVeR

Comment: Well 404 means that the api is not found, so try to check if you have errors in the path.

Comment: Sorry, 400 not 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can direct the bad request error in the following way:

```
@ExceptionHandler
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public void handle(HttpMessageNotReadableException e) {
    //do something here in case of bad request.
}
```

You can go on and customize according to your needs.

Comment: Mh not work, with this method the return message is the apache 400 default message

Comment: And have you tried to retrun some meaningful object instead of void? I tend to have some kind of a standard error response with error code (not necessarily http status code), error message and the root cause description (e.getMessage() for example).

Comment: @PetarMitrovic You can return anything, as from any API in a controller.

Comment: @NiVeR, I was suggesting you to return some object instead of void so it gets resolved into response body. That way, you should not get Apache's default message.